# How do I replace the second occurrence of string 'AllowOverride None' with 'AllowOverride All' using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'd like to replace the second occurrence of string `AllowOverride None` with `AllowOverride All` in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` using sed.

Here's what it looks like before:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ...
```

This is what I would like it to looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ...
```

I've tried:

```
sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/2' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

But it doesn't change anything. What should I try next?

Comment: People at Superuser might answer that. For this site, it's off-topic. And falsely tagged. It has nothing to do with PHP or Shell.

Comment: To modify a file in place use `-i`, not `-e` as in `sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I just want to change the second occurrence, not all of them

Comment: @narzero Ok, then use your `/2` as in your example. But `-e` modifies a stream while `-i` modifies the file in place. Test it first with `-i~` so you get a `~` backup file.

Comment: Using `sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/2' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` doesn't work either..

Comment: Is this http://regex101.com/r/mY3aS5/2 what you're looking for?

Comment: Shall I paste it as an answer? ;)

Comment: If you would be so kind

Comment: @LinusKleen Marking this question as off-topic is totally nonsense since here's a bunch of questions on topic like 'how to replace that to this; using this or that tool'; furthermore, the text above in this case should be considered as a plain text and not as a config file. Finally, if the OP used a wrong tag(s), be kind and edit it - in other words use your privileges for a constructive move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it using `sed`.

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/2' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Otherwise, it could be done using `negative lookahead` as shown below but `sed` doesn't support it.

Pattern

```
AllowOverride None(?![\s\S]*AllowOverride None)
```

Replacement

```
AllowOverride All
```

[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/mY3aS5/2)

Comment: Using `sed -i 's/AllowOverride None(?![\s\S]*AllowOverride None)/AllowOverride All/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
` but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using awk:

```
awk '/AllowOverride/ && ++i==2 {sub(/None/,"All")}1' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

When "AllowOverride" is matched, `i` is incremented. On the second match, substitute "None" for "All". The `1` at the end of the script is a common shorthand used to print every line (as it evaluates to true). To overwrite the original file, you can redirect the output to a temporary file:

```
awk '...' > tmp && mv tmp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```